# How to use PHP include to build a secure environment?

Tags: php, linux, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I think this is a simple question but I would like to have a correct vision of the problem.

I created an EC2 instance on Amazon using Amazon Linux AMI.
Then I installed Apache and php55 like per instructions on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html. I also set permissions on /var/www directories as per the same guide.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo groupadd www
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
[ec2-user ~]$ find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

Let's consider this scenario. It is only for testing purpose, then we will implement the real application:

- I have a PHP web application that has one configuraton file config.php where we store some important info for security of the application, like db credential, login criteria.
- To protect it, I put the config.php in a "/matteotest" directory under /var/ set to 755; I created /matteotest outside document root to increase security
- In some files I included the config.php
- the config.php is actually set 404 so that I will upgrade to 604 only if I will need some changes and then I will downgrade again to 404

Here what I did in detail:

in document root I created 2 files. Both files have 664 permission;
owner = ec2-user and group = www

index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 1.12
 */

include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/global.php');
include(PHP_FILES_PATH.'config.php');
echo '</br>';

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
echo('Calculated result: '.$somma.'</br>');
```

global.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 12.36
 */
define('PHP_FILES_PATH', '/var/matteotest/');
```

Then I created /var/matteotest dir with owner=root and group=root with 755 permission.

Then in /var/matteotest I saved config.php; this file is only a test; in real app I will use it to store for example db connection data.
owner = root and group = root

config.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: matteolatitude
 * Date: 26/03/15
 * Time: 1.15
 */

// vediamo se esegue anche questo script
for ($k = 1; $k <= 4; $k++) {
    $somma .= $k*2;
}
```

I would like to know

1. Is `include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/global.php')` seems to be a good and secure choice? Is there a better and more secure method?
2. Are my permissions (and also owner and groups) a good choice or you would have done in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Is include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/global.php') seems to be a
>   good and secure choice? Is there a bettere and more secure method?

I prefer `include dirname(__FILE__) .'/global.php';` when including from root. Sometimes I define root path as constant using `__FILE__`.

Comment: Thank you.... checking on manual I found that as I'm working with PHP 5.5 I can also use __DIR__ magic constant instead of dirname(__FILE__)

This way:
include(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'global.php');

Comment: @agodoo You didn't give PHP version, so I gave standard response (and tested by myself). But `__DIR__` should be valid as well :)